# Sign of Partial Derivatives From the Level Curves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble with this question as I keep getting the answers incorrect.
[image]

Here is my thinking: for $f_x$, since in the x-direction it says low, so it's negative. For $f_x$, along the y-direction, it says high, so it should be positive.
For $f_{yy}$ along the y-direction, the curves are getting closer, so it should be positive. For $f_{xx}$, along the x-direction, we know the curves are getting further apart, so it should be negative.

Could someone please correct me if I'm wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling right now with the same material.